# c++ in MonoDevelop: clang: error: no input files

Tags: clang, monodevelop

I have a question that is probably trivial, but I can't see the solution now. I have a .cpp file that I would like to run through MonoDevelop. Unfortunately, instead of a small Bantumi simulation, I only get:

```
Building Solution: Bantumi (Debug)

Building: Bantumi (Debug)
Performing main compilation...

Precompiling headers

Compiling source to object files

Generating binary "Bantumi" from object files
g++ -o "/Users/myname/Projects/Bantumi/Bantumi/bin/Debug/Bantumi"   
clang: error: no input files
Build complete -- 1 error, 0 warnings

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 0 warnings
```

From what I found, most people had this problem when there was no such file in the current directory, or the compiler did not have a valid address. However, my file is exactly where the compiler looks for it, but it still produces an error. Do you know what else could lead to this error message?

Thanks a lot! If this type of question has already been solved, you can just send me a link to it.

Comment: Is it possible, that you have a file permission problem? Is it allowed for compiler to access that folder?

Comment: Thanks, Ilya! Yeah, that would make sense. I checked that, but when I tried using Xamarin, I got                                                    `Build failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Build: 1 error, 0 warnings` . So it should be accessible through Xamarin, even if it produces another error. Do you know if there can be something in a code that would trigger this error message?